# Can the value of $\pi$ be the denominator of an angle in radians?

Tags: fractions, pi

I understand that usually problems have $\pi$ in the numerator as this can easily convert to degrees with whole numbers, but is it possible for an angle in radians to be a fraction with $\pi$ in the denominator? I believe this is so as I think $\pi$ is just a constant, but I wanted to confirm.

Comment: Yes, $\pi$ is just like every other real number.  You can speak of angle of $\frac 1{\pi}$ radians if you like.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! *Any* real number between $0$ and $2\pi$ (including $0$, excluding $2\pi$) can be the measure of an angle. Real numbers outside of this range can also be used to describe the measures of angles, but then the measures of angles are not unique – e.g. an angle of measure $3\pi$ is the same as an angle of measure $\pi$.

Comment: An angle $3\pi$ is not necessarily the same as an angle $\pi$. It depends on context. If you spin $100\pi$ radians, then you will certainly be more dizzy than if you spin $0$ radians. But the final direction will be the same in both cases.

Comment: Yes, in this context I am talking specifically about the measure of an angle, not about (e.g.) the winding number of a path around a point. If you spin $100\pi$ radians you will end up in the same place as if you had spun $0$ radians, hence the angles subtended by your original direction and the directions you would be pointed after spinning are the same. Of course the more you spin, the more you spin, but an angle itself is nothing more than an ordered choice of two rays from the same point.

Answer (score 1):

Radians measure the "distance" traveled if you start at a point on the unit circle and move along the arc determined by the angle. So the full circle (three hundred sixty degrees) is $2\pi$ since the unit circle has circumference $2\pi$. On the other hand, a right angle covers a quarter of the circle, hence $2\pi/4=\pi/2$ radians.

This is the only reason why $\pi$ shows up in the numerator so much--its easiest for us to think about angles that take up a "reasonable" fraction of the whole circumference, like a fourth, a third, a half, etc., which correspond to $\pi/2$, $2\pi/3$, and $\pi$ radians, respectively.

But you can still use radians to measure all the other "weird" angles that cover any arclength you like. So this could be $1/\pi$ radians, $1/e$ radians, $\phi$ (golden ratio) radians, etc...